# SE login OpenID redirect blocked in Chrome Canary

Tags: bug, status-declined, login, google-chrome, stack-exchange-openid

It is not possible for me to logon to SE using Chrome Canary. I have to use Canary, because a recent bug prevents flash from loading at all in Chrome for some sites.

Canary seems to adopt security BCPs that are incompatible with what SE does. The following errors are displayed after clicking "StackExchange Account" on the login page:

[image]

The login works in Chrome stable. If I manually follow the OpenID auth link, the login completes successfully.

Comment: This is simply not one of the supported browsers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chrome canary is not supported - it is a moving target, a codebase that is liable to break anything at any time.

To reiterate - browsers in alpha/beta status are not supported.